# Java geotools check if point is contained in polygon with tolerance

Tags: java, geotools, contain

I am using Java Geotools library for check if a POINT(...) is contained in a POLYGON(...).

I have done it with:

```
Geometry sPG = reader.read(wktStartPoint); //startpointgeometry
Geometry sEG = reader.read(wktEndPoint);
if(wktLayerGeo.contains(sPG) || wktLayerGeo.contains(sEG)){
 // do something
}
```

But now I have to set a tolerance: I would check if a point is contained in the polygon with a tolerance distance of 50 km for example.

Can I do it with GeoTools?

Thank you

Comment: Michele. 2 years had it been. I think your question will help me ! I have a list of polygon coordinates `-119.00072399999999 35.36158, -118.99903 35.361576, -118.999026 35.362579, -118.999023 35.363482, -118.999019 35.36432, -118.999408 35.364847999999995` Can you share on how you have coded to check if a point (x,y) is inside the polygon coordinates?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the JTS `buffer` method on your Polygon geometry ([API](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/Geometry.html#buffer(double))):

```
double yourToleranceDistance = 2;
int numberOfSegmentsPerQuadrant = 2;
// get the geometry with your tolerance
Polygon wktLayerGeoWithTolerance = (Polygon) wktLayerGeo.buffer(yourToleranceDistance, numberOfSegmentsPerQuadrant, BufferParameters.CAP_SQUARE);
// continue with your code...
if(wktLayerGeoWithTolerance.contains(sPG) || wktLayerGeoWithTolerance.contains(sEG)){
     // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `DWithin` operator which will check if a point (or other geometry) is within a provided distance of a geometry. Note the distance is always in the units of your data's projection regardless of the units string.

```
double distance = 10.0d;

FilterFactory2 ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2();
Filter filter = ff.dwithin(ff.property("POLYGON"), ff.literal(point), distance, uom.toString());

return featureSource.getFeatures(filter);
```